# Why do we call cinema The Seventh Art?

Tags: etymology, expressions

Why do we call cinema The Seventh Art? Why not sixth or fifth?

Comment: As a kid in the 1960's in Cuba .I remember a TV show call El Septimo Arte.it was all about movies . The 7th Art term is used thru out Latin America and Europe. No one seems to even heard of the term in The USA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hegel first [classified](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_des_arts) five arts in [Lectures on Aesthetics](http://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/works/ae/index.htm):

1. Architecture
2. Sculpture
3. Painting
4. Music
5. Poetry

In 1911, [Ricciotto Canudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricciotto_Canudo) wrote **The Birth of the Sixth Art** arguing that Cinema was #6; later he redefined dance as #6, making cinema the seventh art.

The term is much more common in French than in English today.